# bootstrap navbar hiding text/pictures under it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've added a bootstrap navbar to the top of my page and want to add some sort of carousel of pictures under it. for some reason i cannot get anything to display under the navbar! i know it seems really basic but i unfortunately need another pair of eyes on it. thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="img/small.png" alt="" />
</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Full Menu & Taps</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Happy Hour</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Upcoming">watch!</a></li>
          <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">About </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed give element under it `margin-top: 60px;`

Give as much as high is your navigation.

I think you will see it.

And your body tag is empty i think it should be on body tag, you can put it in `<header>` tag not `<head>` i think. Like `<body><header><nav>`